# Why are preflight requests categorized as 3rd party requests in chrome DevTools network tab?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, network-programming, devtools, preflight

I'm looking at network tab in chrome devtools and see that preflight requests are categorized into 3rd party requests whereas the actual cors request for which preflight request was made is categorised into xhr/fetch? Shouldn't both be categorized into 3rd party requests?

[image]

[image]